# Ford Figo starting problem

Tags: ford, starting, diesel

I have 2012 Ford Figo diesel.I recently got the work done for clutch plate and wheel bearing.
Now the car is not starting itself. I got it checked by a local mechanic also he said everything is fine except that diesel is not coming into the engine.
The oil input pipe in engine is not getting the required fuel because of which it is not starting. Can you please help me out on the issue and possible reasons why fuel is not coming.

Comment: Just wondering how did you solved this problem as I'm facing this problem since long time.

Answer (score 4):

A lack of fuel getting to the engine can be one of several things:

- No fuel in the tank
- Failed fuel pump
- Blocked fuel filter
- Blocked fuel line
- Blocked tank inlet vent (if air can't get into the tank, fuel can't get out)
- Airlock in the fuel lines

You may have more than one pump and/or filter, as some diesel cars have a low-pressure pump in the tank and a high-pressure one near the engine.

The most common cause of blockages is flakes of dirt, sediment or rust from the bottom of the tank - do you often run the fuel level very low? It's always best not to let the level run "into the red", as sucking the fuel from the bottom of the tank will pick up sediment.

Remove the filler cap while listening for any signs of air inrush (a blocked vent would cause a vacuum in the tank). Check the lines underneath for any signs of damage, corrosion or perishing. Inspect the filter(s), and try to re-prime the pump - an easy job on old-fashioned Bosch fuel pumps, but probably harder on a modern Ford. If they are electric pumps, listen for them priming when you switch on the ignition.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the key in 2 position and check if you hear 8 beeps. These 8 beeps are mandatory for normal startup. If you hear 8 beeps then depress clutch and press accelator between 1/4 to 1/2. Switch the key to ignition gently.

If you don't hear 8 beeps, get fuel pump checked. It must have choaked.

Hope this helps.